# Issue with objects overlapping in a Unity 2D grid system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am trying to make a push-block game on Unity2D and of course need the blocks to not be able to overlap if the player were to try and push one block on a tile which is already occupied by another.
I've been running into issues with my code where despite my best efforts I cannot seem to make it work!

I've only added what I believe are the key parts of my code.

Movable Object script:

```
public class MovableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
private GridManager _gridManager;    
public float currentX;
public float currentY;

void MoveToRightTile(Transform protagonistTransform)
{         
    Debug.Log("Right");
    float newX = transform.position.x + _gridManager._tileSize;
    float newY = transform.position.y;

    int targetGridX = _gridManager.GetGridX(newX);
    int targetGridY = _gridManager.GetGridY(newY);
    
    if(_gridManager.MinX < newX && newX < _gridManager.MaxX)
    {
        IsWithinGridBounds = true;
    }
    else
    {
        IsWithinGridBounds = false;
    }

    if (IsWithinGridBounds && canMove && !_gridManager.IsTileOccupied(targetGridX, targetGridY))
    {
        Vector2 newPosition = new Vector2(newX, newY);
        transform.position = newPosition;

        // Update the grid position in the GridManager
        _gridManager.MoveGameObjectTo(this, _gridManager.GetGridX(newX), _gridManager.GetGridY(newY));
        newX = currentX;
        newY = currentY;
    }
}
```

Grid Manager Script:

```
  public class GridManager : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private int _width, _height;
[SerializeField] private Tile _tilePrefab;
[SerializeField] private GameObject _gameObjectPrefab;


private GameObject[,] _gameObjects;

    public void RegisterObjectAt(MovableObject movableObject, int x, int y)
{
    _gameObjects[x, y] = movableObject.gameObject;
}
public bool IsTileOccupied(int x, int y)
{
    // Check if the specified tile is occupied
    return _gameObjects[x, y] != null;
}
 public void MoveGameObjectTo(MovableObject movableObject, int x, int y)
{
    int currentX = GetGridX(movableObject.transform.position.x);
    int currentY = GetGridY(movableObject.transform.position.y);

    // Check if the destination is valid (within grid bounds and unoccupied)
    if (x >= 0 && x < _width && y >= 0 && y < _height && _gameObjects[x, y] == null)
    {
        // Clear the current grid position
        _gameObjects[currentX, currentY] = null;

        MarkTileUnoccupied(currentX, currentY);
        // Update the grid position
        movableObject.UpdateGridPosition();

    }
}

public void MarkTileUnoccupied(int x, int y)
{
    _gameObjects[x, y] = null;
}
```

Comment: have you tried using a tilemap instead?

Comment: @BugFinder I haven't... Would it work for a push block game? If so could you give me some points to start with as I'm not really sure how I'd make it work. I'd also prefer to just fix my current method as its taken me quite some time already, and because time is tight I am worried starting something new may take too long.

Comment: well tilemaps work a lot like arrays  so you can test whats in them, or move them around with ease

Comment: Should `_gridManager.MaxX < newX` be `< targetGridX`?  Hard to decipher what those min values are, if they are position or grid based values.  Also at the end in the `IsWithinGridBounds....` condition, you are setting `newX = currentX`, looks wrong since newX will be discarded immediately after.